# iOS webapp open from another webapp or safari

Tags: ios, web-applications, external-links

Is there a way I could make links to my website open in the web app if the user has it installed on their home screen? Like if there is a link to my website in the Facebook app, how do I tell the iPhone to open the web app and not safari?

I know native apps can do this, and you can open one app from another... but can the same be done with a web app and native app or two web apps (open one web app from another)?

It's probably super far fetched, but it would be a nice feature!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it would be a nice feature... but unfortunately you can't yet. iOS 8 may be?